# how to code with debug options in java

Tags: java

I am trying to learn the trick on how to run the code which prints a lot of stuff when the debug flag is on.

How is that done in java.

A very naive way I can think of is have the debug flag in all the methods i write

and write something like

```
 if (this.debug == true){
 System.out.println("blah blah");
  }
```

But there should be much more elegant way rather than having all these ifs in code?

Also, is there a way I can get the line number of certain execution in code:

For example if there is an exception

```
            try:
```

/* line number 22 */

```
 catch Exception e{
         //print that exception occured in above line number??
    }
```

Probably very lame questions.
THanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use logging framework that will do it for you - for example : [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html)

**For example:**

```
log.debug("some text");
```

now in logging configuration properties file choose to enable disabled debug logging statements

**See**

- [log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
- [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Simple example from log4j API

```
private Logger _debugLogger = Logger.getLogger(yourClassName.class);
//For info mode
_debugLogger.info("Some Messages");
//or for debug mode
_debugLogger.debug(MessageFormat.format("Some message {0},{1},{2}",variable0, variable1,variable2));
```